# how can i get true logic condition to true in java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, logic

That's my while loop, and the question is, how can i get a true condition?

`s` and `t` are `Integer` variables

```
while (s<=t && s>=t && s!=t )
```

**EDIT**

**tl;dr** the original question stated:

`s` and `t` are `int` variables *(and OP commented they are not `Integer` variables)*

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: is this some kind of brain teaser? also, why would not a simple `if` do for the sake of illustration rather than `while`?

Comment: Strange question.  What kind of a problem are you trying to sovle?  I suggest you re-write the entire expression.  Or if it's a homework problem, tag it so!

Comment: Hint: In Java, `==` and `.equals()` are different.

Comment: @JackManey I thought that too, but it says `int`, not `Integer`.

Comment: Probably related to atomicity, multi threading, synchronization?

Comment: Yes, that was my exam question in the university

Comment: and yes these variables are int, not Integer

Comment: Maybe when other thread updates these values between each test.

Comment: and this is pretty pretty hard to happen @Pshemo :)

Comment: @HericDenis true, but it is not impossible :)

Comment: Sure @Pshemo not really ;D

Comment: Can some one confirm the result determination is thread safe? Even if it isn't it'd be near impossible to actually make the change to variables after two checks have taken place. So I guess this comment answers the question.

Comment: @ThomasNyiri you say "and yes these variables are int, not Integer" and than accept the answer that uses Integer?

Comment: yes, i thought that i should have to declare s,t to int, but not!

Comment: @ThomasNyiri I bet 99% of people who read this question would have answered _if they are Integer_ but your question and comment says they are not `Integer`. I would at least update the question, if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By boxing the primitive value in an object:

```
    Integer s = new Integer(5);
    Integer t = new Integer(5);

    boolean rslt = (s <= t && s >= t && s !=  t);

    System.out.println("Result = " + rslt);
```

The `rslt` boolean here will indeed evaluate to `true`.

However, the following would return false:

```
s <= t && s >= t && !s.equals(t)
```

it is because in Java, for objects, `==` means that it is indeed the same instance, while `equals` is left up to be implemented by every class and typically means that the core values of the compared objects are the same -- while not necessarily being the same class instance (AKA object).  The `> and <` for boxed primitives are evaluated agaist the primitive value, however `==` is checking the object identity.

Answer (score 3):

Never!
`s` and `t` are `int` variables, so when `s == t` the third operand will fail, when `s != t` one of the first two operands will fail.

Possible, but unlikely, if they are declared as `volatile int s, t;` in a multi-threaded application.

**EDIT**

Question has been modified. Now `s` and `t` are Integer variables, which makes the answers referring to `Integer` objects more relevant.

Comment: certainly:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806883/how-can-i-get-true-logic-condition-to-true-in-java/13807000#13807000

Comment: @foampile This answer was from when the OP said they were `int` not `Integer`, so this was correct when it was posted.

Answer (score 1):

It actually is possible:

```
public class EqualsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer x = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        Integer y = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

        if(x <= y && y <= x && y !=x)
        {
            System.out.println("equal");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling this and running it with two equal integer arguments produces:

```
$ java EqualsTest 5 5
equal
```

The reason that this works is due to [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) and the fact that, for objects, `==` only checks whether or not the references are the same (which, in the case above, they are not).

Comment: What you write is correct, but OP clearly states his variables are `int`, not `Integer`.

Comment: @jlordo -- i don't see that anywhere in the OP...  am i missing something?

Comment: @foampile check the comments!

> " these variables are int, not Integer."

Comment: given that it's a `homework` question, mixing the concepts of objects and primitives could be expected as a result of lack of expertise

Comment: And a waste of 28 minutes on a pretty straight forward question.

Comment: OK, i see now where he says it and explicitely disclaims it from being a primitive.  i still think he may be missing the requirement of the assignment.  if indeed it must be an `int`, i have no solution.  also, the `int vs Integer` ambiguity should be edited into the OP for the ease of consumption, rather than scanning through comments in fine print

Answer (score 0):

Never man, no way.

s<=t && s>=t returns true if s == t, and s == t && s != t returns false forever.

Comment: @ThomasNyiri, you should study [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic).

Answer (score 0):

You cant the only way first two conditions result true is when s is equal to t and the third conditions negates this fact.

Hence i dont think its possible

Comment: the trick is, == is not the same as .equals().  Sometimes things that are not == can be .equals()...

Answer (score 0):

If the two values are accessible by multiple threads (either `static`, or members variables of an object shared between multiple threads), you could do this:

Thread 1:

```
s = 1; // 1
t = 1; // 2
t = 2; // 5
```

Thread 2:

This is equivalent to your expression but easier to label.

```
boolean result = s <= t; // 3
if(result) {
    result = s >= t; // 4
}
if(result) {
    result = s != t; // 6
}
```

Assuming everything happens in the order given by the commented numbers, then at the end of thread 2's code, `result` will be true.

So, thread 1 sets `s` and `t` to be equal, then thread 2 checks that they're equal, then thread 1 sets them to be not equal, then thread 2 checks that they're not equal.

There are more complicated situations where this could be true, but this is the simplest one I could think of.